# xkb: inverted keyboard layout indication

Tags: xkb

I use scroll LED as keyboard layout indicator (off - English, on - Russian). It works great on the PS/2 keyboard at home. 
And it works in general on my work computer (USB keyboard). But sometimes I have this LED being out of sync.  I assume it is related to sporadic USB device disconnection/connection (there are appropriate messages in dmesg).
After that I can change layout, but LED state continue to be inversed.

The question is: how to sync led with current keyboard layout?

P.S. used xkb options: `grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll`

Comment: You can set LED states with `xset -led`, but I've no idea if this syncs with the internal keyboard state. Worth a try, though.

Comment: I tried xset, it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I can fix it such way:set LED to ON state;disconnect keyboard and connect it again. After that LED is OFF and stay synced for a several hours.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue with these commands (idea from [an Ubuntu bug discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/267999/comments/22)):

```
xmodmap -e 'remove lock = Caps_Lock'
setxkbmap -option
```

The keyboard was then reset to default settings: US layout and Caps Lock with the default functionality (and LED which is not inverted). After that, I reapplied my keyboard layout settings. In most popular window managers, that would be done from GUI, but I invoked `setxkbmap` manually:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps
```

Not sure if the initial LED state affects whether the commands work, probably you have to try it several times.